# Подключение к php c++

Tags: php, c++

В интернете часто вижу:
Если у вас долго выполняется `php function`, то советуем сделать её на `c++`.

Много ответов данного типа, но вопрос: как мне к `php` подключить `c++`?

Comment: Нельзя же вроде подключать (`require`) открытый `.cpp`

Comment: А если написать на чистом C - то можно использовать FFI.

Comment: Если Вам нужен интерпретатор, встраиваемый в С++ код, то могу предложить Open Basic. В нем можно подключать С++ функции прямо к исполняющей системе интерпретатора, без лишних прокладок. И отлаживаться прямо в С++ отладчике. Краткое описание можно посмотреть в моем профиле. Там же есть и ссылка, откуда можно скачать проект.

Comment: Либо использовать что-то наподобие [PHP-CPP](http://www.php-cpp.com/) для создания плагина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно написать динамическую библиотеку на С/C++ с использованием Zend Engine. А после этого её подключать к PHP.

[Первый пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/98862/), [второй пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/125597/)